# Binding model to view with Spring Web Flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-webflow

i've trobule with binding model to form view, im getting error

`Property or field 'city' cannot be found on null`

I'm trying to bind `String place.location.city` to my view

```
<form role="form" th:action="${flowExecutionUrl}" th:object="${place}" method="post">
 <input class="form-control" th:field="*{location.city}"/>
<!-- ... -->
</form>
```

This is my xml of subflow where i'm getting error

```
<view-state id="mapView" view="/places/add/location" model="place">
    <transition on="locationSelected" to="locationReady"/>
</view-state>

<end-state id="locationReady">
</end-state>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error msg is telling you that either Location or Place is null.

If I had to guess you probably did not initialize the model Place inside your flow xml **before** entering the view-state mapView

```
<set name="flowScope.place" value ="new your.class.path.model.Place()"/>
```

Though you will probably want to use a Factory Method to init Place (so you can also init Location in 1 call)